# how to customize bar button but keep the segue?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have added a bar button item in my navigation bar and linked a segue from the button to another view controller.

Now I tried to custmize the look of this button by

```
    UIButton *mapButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
    [mapButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
    [mapButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    [showAllButton setCustomView:mapButton];
```

The segue is no longer being called when I tap on it. What went wrong?

Thanks!

Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually make a call to perform the segue, like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDeviceDetail" sender:self];
```

So if you set a target and selector on your button, and call that within the selector, you should be able to perform the segue.

Just remember to name your segue in interface builder to be able to do this, and then include that identifier in the call you make.

Answer (score 0):

well, for one thing, you don't add a target to this new mapButton.
Not familiar with storyboards but I'm sure this new button doesn't work if you don't add a target and selector...